# ./configure not working when installing python 3.6.1

Tags: software-installation, python

I installed python 3.6.1 from python.org and extracted the file. Then I did:

```
cd Desktop
cd Python-3.6.1
./configure
```

But then I got an error:

```
./configure: line 2328 config.log: Permission denied
./configure: line 2338 config.log: Permission denied
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: enter this command `sudo chown yourUsername:yourUsername ~/Desktop/Python-3.6.1` and then try again to configure

Comment: Related: [`./configure: line 2178 config.log permission denied`](//superuser.com/q/607829/238583)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've done some stuff with the Python 3.6.1 source code bundle as super-user and now the file ownership is screwed up. Typically there's no need to build a source code bundle as super-user. The subsequent installation (i. e. `make install` or `checkinstall`) may require super-user privileges if you want to install the software in a system location.

To re-transfer the file ownership to yourself run:

```sh
sudo chown -R "$USER:" ~/Desktop/Python-3.6.1
```

Comment: that did work! But the only problem now is that I don't have a 3.6.1 IDLE and tkinter won't work. Please help

Comment: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. Thanks.